# Is there a way to make a function rerun after a screensize change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have 2 media queries 1024 and up, and 1023 and down.

If a function runs in the 1023 and down, is there a way to make it re run if the screen is changed to 1024 and up?

I am making bars that will load, and if they load at a smaller screen then their data is slightly off.

I have tried using this to no avail:

JS:

```
if($(window).width() >= 1024){
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.bar').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.load').each(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                width: ($(this).parent().width() - 110) * $(this).parent().attr('data-percent') / 100
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
}, 5000);
}

else {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.bar').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.load').each(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                width: ($(this).parent().width() - 110) * $(this).parent().attr('data-percent') / 100
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
}, 5000);
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: you might look for this http://api.jquery.com/resize/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, the `$(window).resize()` event would do the trick:

```
var resizeTimer;

    //Event to handle resizing
    $(window).resize(function () 
    {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(Resized, 100);
    });

    //Actual Resizing Event
    function Resized() 
    {
        alert("Resized");
    };
```

[simple jSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chufol/f2a5V/)

Notes:

The code uses this trick /concept to avoid firing too many times and burdening your UI:

http://joshbroton.com/hooking-up-to-the-window-onscroll-event-without-killing-your-performance/

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Comment: Wouldn't this be constantly firing the function? When in reality, I'll only need it once if it drops down below 1023, or once if it go above 1024?

Comment: @user4470749 Yes, the resize event fires constantly, just like the window.scroll() event. But this is a normal thing to track / trap and manipulate. Note the writer of the 2nd bottom link (google him).

Comment: My mistake, I just read your edit. As far as this, it's probably the best option, I'm just tinkering with it to stop the massive delay on it.

Comment: Alright, I had to run the function twice, 1 out side of the debounce w/ a delay, then run 1 in the debounce w/o a delay. Gonna go ahead and call this solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to exploit CSS's media query facility as the basis for a trigger. I would consider placing the code within a div. When the screen size changes, re-reference the div under different @media screen settings. You might need to duplicate the code under two different div names and flip-flop the references as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
    if (window.foo) clearTimeout(window.foo);

    window.foo = setTimeout(function () {
        //reload your page after resize (not the best way... but works)
        this.location.reload(false);

        //or reexecute your function (better :) )
        //...
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I would do this, except the fact that I have a page-load screen on the site and I think constantly reloading after a browser size change would get pretty ridiculous.

Comment: Note: `.bind()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.6 and replaced with `.on()` - but you are correct in pointing out that if the markup is injected after the DOM was rendered, then delegation is necessary.