# Re-order HTML or PHP based on screensize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Thank you for reading, a newbie question because I am not very experienced.

I am trying to make a desktop header for a responsive site. The site is good for mobile viewing but if someone it viewing it at more than it's maximum width (1000 px) I want to redesign the header.

---

I have a php file which calls out the header file

I also have the header html file:

```
<html>
<body>


<div id="fun1">
<?php echo $fun1; ?>
</div>

<div id="fun2">
  <?php echo $fun2; ?>
  </div>

<div id="fun3">
<?php echo $fun3; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

These 's need to be reordered when the screen size is over 1000 px only.

Is there a way to do this by building in a conditional mix of php and js/css or html and js/css into either of the files which I mentioned or by doing something else all together?

Thanks for your time, I appreciate any help you can give me. I apologize if I asked a bad question.

Comment: Hello Vlad. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have asked a rather generic question so you will probably not get as much help as you may want. I suggest including the specific output you are wanting. Perhaps a screenshot of the divs as they are on mobile, and how you want them re-arranged on desktop.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I apologize for being a noob

Comment: We're here to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at using media queries in your CSS, such as:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

These sizes are just examples, for a more detailed description I suggest looking [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Yes, using media queries will mean that you can change specify different CSS values, which will trigger dependant on the users resolution. Using my example, If a user has a screen resolution of 300px or less, their background colour will be red. How you go about it using media queries depends on your circumstances, aka if your data is hard-coded or being gathered dynamically (from a db etc).

Answer (score 1):

Further to Tommy's insightful answer, +1, note that you can also use the jQuery `resize()` method.

Full explanation and jsFiddle example here:

[Is there a way to make a function rerun after a screensize change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885644/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-function-rerun-after-a-screensize-change/28885781#28885781)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the desired layout is, you can use media queries to specify when you want the layout to change. To change the flow of the document you can use either the `position` property to move the `div`s around manually (an OK solution if the container has a fixed width that you can move your `div`s around in) or the `float` property to move the `div`s around a bit.

The "solution" below shows the three `div`s stacked on mobile. When viewed in full-screen they should be side-by-side with the second `div` on the end.

```css
/**
 * Default / mobile
 */
div {
  width:100%;
  height:5em;
}
#fun1 {
  background:red;
}
#fun2 {
  background:blue;
}
#fun3 {
  background:green;
}

/**
 * Greater than 700 pixels.
 * Place divs next to each other
 */
@media (min-width:700px) {
  div {
    float:left;
    width:32%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
  }
  div + div {
    margin-left:1%;
  }
  
  /**
   * Move #fun2 to the right
   */
  #fun2 {
    float:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="fun1">
  Fun 1
</div>

<div id="fun2">
  Fun 2
</div>

<div id="fun3">
  Fun 3
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries in your css. Your HTML is fine as it is.